# PHP & JavaScript select and setup printers

Tags: javascript, php, printing, printers, network-printers

[image: Printer selection]

Take a look on the screenshot above, it's an Windows based app. I was wondering if this possible to done in PHP & JavaScript?

What I want to achieve is, user in **module 1**, will automatically select **printer #1** and print it directly without display the print dialog. For **module 2** will use **printer #2**.

I know this may sounds impossible due to security issue. But just share to me any possible solution that you know. Thank in advanced.

**UPDATE: Feb 18, 2016 17:40**

The module that I mention will actually generate a PDF file, I not sure if this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figured out the solution.

1. I create a C# Windows Form application as a wrapper, by using [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp), then I load the web app inside
2. From the Windows app, I can get the installed printers, and inject the list via JavaScript to the browser. Then it can be saved.
3. For my case, I need to print out the downloaded pdf file directly, thus I use [Foxit](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/) to print it out. *(by running batch script in C# app)*

I have blog it down, [refer here](http://jsl.im/1W5ekme)